# Is it possible to manually resume a session in selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, browser-session

Is there a way to hand off a selenium session to a browser locally.
I'd like to run a script and somehow release the session or pause it so that I can resume testing from that point. Is this possible with selenium. I'm not sure if there is a term for this already.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the tests on your local machine, just make sure the test-code does not call `driver.quit();` or `driver.close();` or `driver.Dispose();`. For example by commenting it out and running only one test. The browser should stay open at the end of the test.

The default browser idle timeout is 30 minutes, this means you should be able to keep working in that browser session for 30 minutes. This should be more than enough for most Selenium/WebDriver debugging things. I guess it is also enough for most exploratory testing sessions. You can extend this default timeout by starting the Selenium server manually with `-timeout seconds`, but I can't find the official documentation for this. [This page](https://siteobservers.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201989070-Start-selenium-server-with-additional-command-line-arguments) has some info about the command-line arguments..

Just testing it on my localmachine, removed `driver.quit()` from my test cleanup and notwthe browser is already open for some minutes.